# Spring data jpa native query with null parameter (PostgreSQL)

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

The question is how to make my native query accept a null parameter?

Here is my query:

```
    @Query(value = "SELECT " +
            "   summaries.event_type as \"eventType\", " +
            "   summaries.institution_id as \"institutionId\", " +
            "   identifiers.id as \"studentIdentifierId\", " +
            "   identifiers.name as \"studentIdentifierName\" " +
            "FROM summaries " +
            "LEFT JOIN roles ON summaries.student_id=roles.id " +
            "LEFT JOIN identifiers ON roles.identifier_id=identifiers.id " +
            "WHERE " +
            "   summaries.student_id IS NOT NULL AND " +
            "   summaries.event_type IN (:eventTypes) AND " +
            "   (:identifierId IS NULL OR roles.identifier_id=:identifierId) " +
            "GROUP BY " +
            "   summaries.institution_id, " +
            "   summaries.student_id, " +
            "   identifiers.id, " +
            "   identifiers.name, " +
            "   summaries.event_type",
            nativeQuery = true)
    List<CustomProjection> findByCustomCondition(
            @Param("identifierId") Long identifierId,
            @Param("eventTypes") List<String> eventTypes);
```

And now when I pass `identifierId` as null, I'm receiving the error:

```
InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet.
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: bigint = bytea
  HINT: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

It seems like the line `(:identifierId IS NULL OR roles.identifier_id=:identifierId)` causes a problem here, but can't really find a good solution, as from my understanding it should work normally (when I use this query directly on pgAdmin it works as it should, so I'm quite sure it's an issue related with mapping).

I tried to cast the identifier (`cast(:identifierId as bigint)`), but it didn't helped out.

PS. it's kinda legacy project, so these are versions that I use:

```
compile group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-jpa', version: '1.11.6.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: '42.2.2'
compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '5.2.17.Final'
```

Comment: What type do you use for `roles.identifier_id`?

Comment: I use the `bigint`

Comment: The error seems to be related to extraction of the result set, what are the fields of the custom projection?

Comment: String - eventType, Long - institutionId, Long - studentIdentifierId, String - studentIdentifierName. And when I pass identifierId as e.g. `0L` it doesn't break, so I'm not sure if it's related with projection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common problem with Hibernate + PostgreSQL, and the solution is to implement that method yourself, instead of having Spring do it for you. Within the implementation you have to do something like this

```
List<CustomProjection> findByCustomCondition(
        @Param("identifierId") Long identifierId,
        @Param("eventTypes") List<String> eventTypes) {
     // entityManager is acquired with the @PersistenceContext annotation as an injectable
     Query q = entityManager.createNativeQuery(..., CustomProjection.class);
     // the important part:
     q.setParameter("identifierId", 0L);
     q.setParameter("identifierId", identifierId);
     ...
```

First call to `setParameter` ensures Hibenate uses the correct type setter, second call overrides the first value without having executed the query, and skips type detection.

Answer (score 0):

Modify query by adding space between `roles.identifier_id=:identifierId` should be like`roles.identifier_id= :identifierId`

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the following instead: `(cast(:identifierId as bigint) IS NULL OR roles.identifier_id=:identifierId)`

Answer (score 0):

As it was mentioned in the @coladict's answer it looks like, unfortunately, you can not do that you want with clean Spring Data JPA solution. So, you can rewrite you query using `EntityManager` and hibernate specific `setParameter` that allows explicitly specify binding parameter type:

```java
import org.hibernate.type.LongType;

// ...

List<CustomProjection> results = entityManager.createNamedQuery("find_by_custom_condition" )
.unwrap(org.hibernate.query.Query.class)
.setParameter("identifierId", identifierId, LongType.INSTANCE)
.getResultList();
```

Then you can use `@NamedNativeQuery` with `@SqlResultSetMapping` to map native query results to the `CustomProjection`. See examples in the hibernate [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#sql-scalar-named-queries).

See also [this article](https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-query-setparameter-hibernate/) about `setParameter` usage in JPA and Hibernate query.

Answer (score 0):

So this is not the exact answer to the question above, but I was facing a similar issue, I figured I would add it here, for those that come across this question.

I was using a native query where the in clause of the query might be null, ie:

```sql
WHERE (cm.first_name in (:firstNames) OR :firstNames is NULL)
```

I was getting the `bytea` error, in the end I was able to send an empty list.

```java
(null == entity.getFirstName()? Collections.emptyList() : entity.getFirstName())
```

In this case, sending the empty list to the resolver worked, where as null did not.

hope this saves some time for people who come across this question looking for how to pass null to a list parameter of a native query.

Answer (score 0):

Following code also worked for me when booleanParameterValue is null. My database is Oracle and, application is using jpql and hibernate.

```
Query query = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("findBankAccountInfos");
query.setParameter("booleanParameter", Boolean.FALSE);
query.setParameter("booleanParameter", booleanParameterValue);
```

Otherwise application is throwing following exception:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected BINARY got NUMBER
```

Comment: You know, I really thought this was only a problem when using PostgreSQL, but this year I encountered it with MSSQL, and now you're confirming it for another database? I do hope the new type system in Hibernate 6 fixed that.